# Android XWalkView / XWalkWebView

Tags: android, html, cordova, video, webview

I am using **XWalkView** to load my html5 site on device, my site contains a lot of js and video.

Here is my code:

```
public class ActivityXWalkWebView extends Activity {

  public static final String TAG = "ActivityXWalkWebView";

  private XWalkView xWalkWebView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xwalk_web_view);

    XWalkPreferences.setValue("enable-javascript", true);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.ALLOW_UNIVERSAL_ACCESS_FROM_FILE, true);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.JAVASCRIPT_CAN_OPEN_WINDOW, true);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.SUPPORT_MULTIPLE_WINDOWS, true);

    xWalkWebView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);
    xWalkWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    xWalkWebView.load(Constants.PATH_TO_INDEX_HTML_FROM_ASSETS, null);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (xWalkWebView != null) {
        xWalkWebView.pauseTimers();
        xWalkWebView.onHide();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (xWalkWebView != null) {
        xWalkWebView.resumeTimers();
        xWalkWebView.onShow();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (xWalkWebView != null) {
        xWalkWebView.onDestroy();
    }
  }
```

All works good, but my videos and some pop-up windows sometimes freezes.
Maybe I have lost some settings of my XWalkView?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile?